# Can I make my Alteryx RegEx parse conditional?

Tags: regex, alteryx

I receive messages with the fields below. I want to group and extract the user inputs. Majority of submissions contain all fields and the regex works great. Problem comes in when someone removes additional lines if let's say they only need to fill in down to Amount 1

```
Name:
Number:
Amount:
Old Code:
Code 1:
Amount 1:
Code 2:
Amount 2:
Code 3:
Amount 3:
Code 4:
Amount 4:
```

---

I'm using Alteryx to parse the message contents and have success with my current regex but want to be ready for unavoidable user submission inconsistency

```
Name:(.+)\sNumber:(.+)\sAmount:(.+)\sOld Code:(.+)\sCode 1:(.+)\sAmount 1:(.+)\sCode 2:(.*?)\sAmount 2:(.*?)\sCode 3:(.*?)\sAmount 3:(.*?)\sCode 4:(.*?)\sAmount 4:(.*?[^-]*)
```

Is it possible to have Alteryx return parsed results from a message even if a listed field is deleted?

[Alteryx issue with new cascading regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fhs6.png)

Comment: Is this a form ? How much control does the user have in modifying the "form" ?

Comment: I've distributed an outlook template for user submissions but a user has full capability to modify/delete lines

Comment: Well, we could do an _out-of-order_ regex for the lines and relax the line parsing a bit. Want to try that ?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can always do a cascading nested optional grouping around the
lines to just match what's valid up to a point.
This expects the form lines to be in order. If it's not, a different type
of regex is needed - an out-of-order regex ( see the bottom regex ) .

Both these regex are for Perl 5.10

```
(?-ms)Name:(.*)(?:\s+Number:(.*)(?:\s+Amount:(.*)(?:\s+Old[ ]+Code:(.*)(?:\s+Code[ ]+1:(.*)(?:\s+Amount[ ]+1:(.*)(?:\s+Code[ ]+2:(.*)(?:\s+Amount[ ]+2:(.*)(?:\s+Code[ ]+3:(.*)(?:\s+Amount[ ]+3:(.*)(?:\s+Code[ ]+4:(.*)(?:\s+Amount[ ]+4:(.*?[^-]*))?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/9oKXEE/1

For out-of-order matching, use this

```
(?m-s)\A(?:[\S\s]*?(?:(?(1)(?!))^\h*Name\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(2)(?!))^\h*Number\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(3)(?!))^\h*Amount\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(4)(?!))^\h*Old\h*Code\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(5)(?!))^\h*Code\h*1\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(6)(?!))^\h*Amount\h*1\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(7)(?!))^\h*Code\h*2\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(8)(?!))^\h*Amount\h*2\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(9)(?!))^\h*Code\h*3\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(10)(?!))^\h*Amount\h*3\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(11)(?!))^\h*Code\h*4\h*:\h*(.*)|(?(12)(?!))^\h*Amount\h*4\h*:\h*(.*?))){1,12}
```

https://regex101.com/r/f2rG1v/1

Comment: trying this I only get one grouped result. Parses the name just fine, but keeps all other message contents in group 1

Comment: It should be ok, have a look at these https://regex101.com/r/9oKXEE/1

https://regex101.com/r/I38jil/1

Comment: Works like a charm on regex101, but Alteryx is capturing everything in group 1? Alteryx uses Perl 5 regex syntax if that helps

Comment: Ive added a new regex and also put some inline flags incase the default is dot-all. Basically, I turned off dot matches newlines in an inline modifier `(?-s)` which will override any default flags at runtime.

Comment: Note - use the out-of-order regex if you can. If a capture group is null, the line wasn't there, if it's empty, the line is there but no input was with it. If the group contains a string, the line was both there and contained data.

Comment: Each regex works flawlessly on regex101, but still can't figure out what's not translating over to the Alteryx syntax. Alteryx is taking the if clause number and making it a group due to the ( ). I've tried replacing with [ ] and dropping both options all together with no luck :(

Comment: `but Alteryx is capturing everything in group 1` Yeah, not sure what you mean by this as group 1 cannot contain anything but _Name:_ data. You should put what it's matching and the code that's used to get this information here or somewhere else that can be seen by readers of this post. Otherwise, you're going to have to wait for an Alteryx expert to divine what it is your problem is. This person may not know regex, then your f**ked again..

Comment: Take a peek at the image link I added to the question. The RegExOut columns on the bottom half of the image should be where each capture group lands but you can see in the top half that it is keeping everything else beyond what would be the person's name in a real scenario

Comment: It looks like you have to physically associate each the capture group construct `(.*)` etc, with each RegExOut field when you construct the regex. I'm not sure since I can't try anything out. Here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUkumoxhCxk Also, there is many links to Alterxy regex via google search. That video seems to be concerned with horizontal fields in a data record while your record is vertical. But the regex matches a complete vertical record.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you don't need to use Regex straight off the bat and given the inconsistent data it could take a while to perfect one regex term...

You can do it this way instead: 
- RecordID first, 
- Then you can use a Text 2 Columns with a new-line (\n) delimiter. Configure this to "Split to Rows". 
- You can then use a Text to Columns to split on the delimter ":".

That will handle additional rows entered etc. At that stage, you can figure out how to clean up the results (filter to remove null lines, multi-row to tag records, cross-tab to create a table etc...). If you want to flag any unknown rows, you can have a Text Input with the required rows and use Find/Replace or Join to separate the data.